# Clojure: How do I convert a string to a long?

Tags: clojure, type-conversion

Let's say you have string "100.0"
How do I convert this to a long type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string "100.0" is the string representation of a Double, so if you try to parse it to a long, you'll get an exception.

Use the methods from the Java primitive wrappers.

```
(let [s "100.0"] (Double/valueOf s))
> 100.0
(let [s "100.0"] (class (Double/valueOf s)))
> java.lang.Double
```

Or if your string is a long, you can parse it to with methods from class java.lang.Long:

```
(let [s "100"] (Long/valueOf s))
> 100
(let [s "100"] (class (Long/valueOf s)))
> java.lang.Long
```

Comment: Note that you cannot pass `Long/valueOf` directly to `map` etc. `(map Long/valueOf ["1" "2"])` returns a syntax error, but `(map #(Long/valueOf %) ["1" "2"])` works.

Answer (score 2):

```
user=> (long (Float/valueOf "100.0"))
100

user=> (type (long (Float/valueOf "100.0")))
java.lang.Long
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user=> (-> "100.0" Double/parseDouble long)
100
```

or

```
user=> (->> "100.0" (re-find #"\d+") Long/parseLong)
100
```

Both `Double/parseDouble` and `Long/parseLong` return primitive numeric values,
whereas `*/valueOf` returns a boxed object.

Answer (score 2):

You can get automatically get the correct Long or Double type with `java.text.NumberFormat`

```
user=> (.parse (java.text.NumberFormat/getInstance) "100.0")
100
user=> (type *1)
java.lang.Long

user=> (.parse (java.text.NumberFormat/getInstance) "100.5")
100.5
user=> (type *1)
java.lang.Double
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `clojure.core` only, `bigdec` will effectively coerce to a `Number` type which you can then coerce to a `Long`.

e.g. whether your string is a long or a double --

```
user=> (long (bigdec "100"))
100
```

or

```
user=> (long (bigdec "100.0"))
100
```